# Does C have 32 or 44 keywords?

Tags: c, keyword

ISO/IEC 9899:2017 C N2176 document link: https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf

There are plenty of sources on world wide web, which say that there are 32 keywords in C langauge, But this document (I think it's a draft version, but there's no much changes as compared to the previous version, right?) has **44 words** that are defined to the **keywords** of C language.

Please explain this.

============================================================

Link to the sources which say that there are 32 keywords in C language:

1. https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/list-all-keywords-c-language
2. https://tutorials.webencyclop.com/c-language/c-keyword/
3. https://www.educba.com/c-keywords/
4. https://www.javatpoint.com/keywords-in-c
5. https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-keywords-reserved-words/
6. https://www.phptpoint.com/c-keywords/
7. https://www.guru99.com/c-tokens-keywords-identifier.html
8. https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-tokens-identifiers-keywords/
9. https://www.w3schools.in/c-tutorial/keywords/

Note: Some of these sites are useful for beginners to learn basic concepts and terminalogies of C.

Comment: Which page in the document that you linked contains the claim?

Comment: Ah, it's on page 334, heading **A.1.2** there's a table `11*4 == 44` keywords.

Comment: They are both correct: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword

Comment: Thank you for posting the links to the other sites - but I note that all of those web-pages with the "32 keywords" claims can be (perhaps unfairly) categorized as low-value, non-authoritative, programming _content farms_ that exist to game google and farm ad clicks. Inaccurate (if not misleading) content is par for the course on sites like those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The claims of there being "32" keywords in C refer to the original ANSI-specified version of C from 1989, aka C89.

  - Because this is the Internet, and because the *real* C specifications are behind [ISO's ridiculous paywall](https://twitter.com/isostandards/status/1367138254470930434) most people so-inclined probably can't fact-check the claim.
  - And it's not a claim *worth* fact-checking: the number of keywords in a language is *utter trivia* of no consequence.
- The ISO/IEC 9899 specification you linked to refers to C17 (the proposed updated C specification in 2017) which postdates C89 by 28 years.
- It should come as no surprise that a future updated revision of a programming language introduces new keywords.

---

Historically, when C was introduced, people *were* impressed by its minimalist syntax and how the language's design effectively *reified* everything by implementing functionality as *library features* instead of *language features* which is what keeps C simple and helps mitigate every language's designer's fears about *feature creep*.

In comparison, C's early contemporaries like COBOL, opted to implement functionality into their own languages as first-class features, which is why [COBOL has over 300 keywords](https://www.ibm.com/docs/zh-tw/iis/9.1?topic=words-cobol-reserved); so I'll admit that using the stark difference in keyword-count does serve as a proxy for language-complexity and by extension: a way to almost quantify *good design*. But using it as the basis for comparing languages today in 2021 is of limited-utility as the most relevant programming languages today<sup>[1](https://twitter.com/isostandards/status/1367138254470930434)</sup> are already either inspired by C or derived from it somehow, and they all share C's decision to do things in the library instead of the language, so *all* those languages similarly have a low keyword count compared to COBOL, SQL, and others, and so that's why C's keyword count just isn't interesting anymore.

---

1: C-inspired or C-derived languages [in use today](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/): C++, Objective-C, Java, Groovy, Swift, C#, JavaScript, TypeScript, Go, PHP, Perl. Other popular languages that aren't modelled on C (like Haskell, OCaml, etc) *do* share C's *library-first* philosophy, but I can't say if C originated it or not - but I feel that languages opting for *library-first* designs is inevitable: the cost to implement language-features is easily ten-fold that of implementing library features.

Comment: yes, I realised that 32 keywords is of C89 version. I just realised that these websites weren't updated. I found one source which has right information related to this, it has also explained (in short) the updation of keywords through each newer version. link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variables-and-keywords-in-c/

Comment: Specifically, the added ones are `inline`, `restrict`, and the ten that start with `_`.

Comment: @Algorithmophile GeeksForGeeks is.. uhh... I just prefer not to talk about that site. It's _not_ W3Schools, but it's hardly better.

Comment: @SteveSummit "You seem to know what you are talking about" - no, I'm just on the spectrum.